# Opencart admin get language for selected store

Tags: php, opencart

In the admin Newsletter, I am loading a couple of language files. How do I set this so that it loads the language for the selected store?

E.g

```
$this->load->model('setting/setting');
$store_settings_config = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting("config", $this->request->post['store_id']);
```

returns [config_language] => en

The problem is that in the store settings the language is save using the language code instead of the language_id and there is no method to load the language by code?

Am I missing something or is this a flaw in opencart code?

Is language_id even needed as a primary key because the language code should always be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix by looping through all of the languages:

```
foreach($this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages() as $lang){               
    if($lang['code'] == $store_settings_config['config_language']){
        $language = new Language($lang['directory']);
        $language->load("sale/contact");
    }
}
```